# In Python how do you use filedialog.askopenfilename() to get just the file name itself

Tags: python, tkinter

I have successfully managed to get tkinter's filedialog imported and used the command

```
file_found = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(file_found)
```

Dialog box opens, I can select and successfully print the full path/file name. What I want to do next is just use the file name so I can use os.rename to change the file's name.

A pointer to the documentation or the how would be gratefully appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using a library?

Comment: `os.path.relpath(file_path)`

Comment: `os.path.basename(file_path)` will do it.  Sujay, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @TimRoberts, winner.  Thank you.  Is there a way on Stack to promote or somehow make your comment the correct answer?

Comment: I can make it an answer, but it's hardly worth the trouble...

Comment: @TimRoberts, ok.  I'm still struggling with Stack with respect to the questions/answer/comments thing on top of Stack telling me I'm asking crummy questions.  Nevertheless, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.basename(file_path)` will that job.  The name comes from the bash `basename` command, which serves the same purpose.